# Attachments stream turns to 0 Byte when sending to multiple email addresses in loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, smtp, email-attachments

I am sending multiple attachments to email addresses in a loop. Attachment is properly getting send to first email address in the list but when it loops ahead for other email addresses in list, the attachment stream in parameter - model becomes 0 in length i. e. 0 bytes.

View Model Code :

```
public class BulkMailViewModel
{
    public string EmailTo { get; set; }

    public string EmailSubject { get; set; }

    public string EmailBody { get; set; }

    public List<HttpPostedFileBase> Attachments { get; set; }

    public BulkMailViewModel()
    {
        Attachments = new List<HttpPostedFileBase>();
    }
}
```

Controller  Code  : Below Controller method runs the loop for email addressed to send email.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SendEmail(BulkMailViewModel model)
    {
        List<HttpPostedFileBase> attachments = new List<HttpPostedFileBase>();
        bool isEmailSentMain = true;
        if (model.Attachments != null && model.Attachments.Any())
        {
            foreach (var attachment in model.Attachments)
            {
                if (attachment != null)
                {
                    attachments.Add(attachment);
                }
            }
        }
        string emailContent = System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(model.EmailBody);
        try
        {
            List<string> clientEmails = new List<string>() { };

            clientEmails.Add("abc@abc.com");
            clientEmails.Add("pqr@pqr.com");

            foreach (var email in clientEmails)
            {
                try
                {
                    bool isEmailSent = false;
                    if (email != null && email != "")
                    {
                        isEmailSent = await SendBulkEmailAsync(email, model.EmailSubject, emailContent, attachments, true);

                        if (!isEmailSent)
                        {
                            isEmailSentMain = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    isEmailSentMain = false;
                    return Json(new { status = isEmailSentMain, type = "continue", message = "Error while sending Email." });
                }
            }

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Json(new { status = false, message = e.ToString()});
        }
    }
```

Mail method Code : This method actually sends the mail.

```
public async Task<bool> SendBulkEmailAsync(string emailTo, string emailSubject, string emailContent, List<HttpPostedFileBase> attachmentList, bool isBodyHtml = false)
    {
        List<HttpPostedFileBase> attachments = attachmentList;
        using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient()
        {
            //My SMTP Settings
        })

        using (var message = new MailAddress("email@abc.com", emailTo))
        {

            if (attachments != null)
            {
                foreach (var attach in attachments)
                {
                    string strFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(attach.FileName);
                    attach.InputStream.Position = 0;
                    Attachment attachFile =
                    new Attachment(attach.InputStream, strFileName, attach.ContentType);
                    message.Attachments.Add(attachFile);
                }
            }
            message.Subject = emailSubject;
            message.Body = emailContent;
            message.IsBodyHtml = isBodyHtml;
            await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Can anybody help with this?

Comment: If the email is the same for everybody why don't you send all at once using blind copy carbon?
Anyways, the problem you have is that SendMailAsync reads the stream and it may even close it, so you can't reuse that. If you can't send all at once then you must create a copy of the streams each time you want to send one email.

Comment: It is just an example. Actually the mail is coming from database.

Comment: But the content is the same for all the recipients on each batch or not?

Comment: Yes the content is same but it is to be sent to customers individually.

Comment: That's what Bcc does, CC (Copy Carbon) sends to every recipient but the receivers see the other recipients, BCC (Blind Copy Carbon) sends the email to every recipient individually.

Comment: Actually the customer will come to know about the mail is sent as bcc. And the requirement says no to use bcc.

Comment: Well, then as I said you must copy the `attach.InputStream` to other stream as `SendMailAsync` will close it after using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must clone the content of the `attach.InputStream` in a local stream to avoid it to be closed by `SendMailAsync`:

```
            foreach (var attach in attachments)
            {
                string strFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(attach.FileName);
                attach.InputStream.Position = 0;
                MemoryStream tempStream = new MemoryStream();
                attach.InputStream.CopyTo(tempStream);
                tempStream.Position = 0;
                Attachment attachFile =
                new Attachment(tempStream, strFileName, attach.ContentType);
                message.Attachments.Add(attachFile);
            }
```

Comment: Hi
Sorry for replying late, there were some issues. This is did not help.

Comment: Hi It got resolved, I just had to give position as 0 to tempStream.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to rewind the stream after the copy, answer updated.